# How can I prevent duplicate results returning from my Oracle query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working on a complex query in an Oracle database and I'm having a problem with duplicate data in the results of the query. The query aims to pull the columns and associated information of a particular table. However, I noticed that the field named PRINTERNAME appears more than once in the results, and I'm guessing it won't be just the PRINTERNAME field.

The query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT
    cols.column_name AS COLUMNNAME,
    cols.data_type AS COLUMNDATATYPE,
    cols.data_length AS COLUMNDATALENGTH,
    MAX(cons.constraint_type) AS PK,
    cons_pk.table_name AS REFPROCNAME,
    cols_pk.column_name AS COLUMNVALUEFIELD,
    CASE WHEN cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ISCHOOSABLE
FROM all_tab_columns cols
LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns cols_pk ON cols.table_name = cols_pk.table_name
                                  AND cols.column_name = cols_pk.column_name
LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons ON cols_pk.owner = cons.owner
                             AND cols_pk.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons_pk ON cons.r_owner = cons_pk.owner AND cons_pk.table_name=cols.table_name
WHERE cols.owner = 'AO' AND cols.table_name = 'MACHINEPRINTER'
GROUP BY cols.column_name, cols.data_type, cols.data_length, cons_pk.table_name, cols_pk.column_name, cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
```

Duplicate PRINTERNAME fields in the results of the query bother me. I'm wondering how I should approach this issue. I'm already using the GROUP BY statement but I'm having a hard time filtering the results properly. Where could I have made a mistake in my query and how can I avoid these duplicate results?

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCWGS.png)

Thanks already for your help!

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**

I tried a few different approaches to avoid duplicate results in my query, but didn't get the results I wanted.

First, I tried grouping the results using the GROUP BY statement. I edited the query as in the question.

However, I still see duplicate `PRINTERNAME` fields in the results. My expectation was to avoid duplicates in results with grouping and to make each column appear only once.

**What actually resulted?**

But when I looked at the results of the query, I found that the `PRINTERNAME` field was still repeated multiple times. So, it looks like this approach I tried didn't properly prevent duplicate results. What could I have done wrong in this case and how can I avoid duplicate results? Thanks already for your help!

Comment: You should post the text directly and not a link to an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you're missing one (or, I'd rather say two) conditions.

This is more or less your original query (with a difference that I added table name to result set, my owner is `SCOTT` and I'm querying the `EMP` table):

```
SQL>   SELECT cols.table_name,
  2           cols.column_name AS COLUMNNAME,
  3           cols.data_type AS COLUMNDATATYPE,
  4           cols.data_length AS COLUMNDATALENGTH,
  5           MAX (cons.constraint_type) AS PK,
  6           cons_pk.table_name AS REFPROCNAME,
  7           cols_pk.column_name AS COLUMNVALUEFIELD,
  8           CASE WHEN cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ISCHOOSABLE
  9      FROM all_tab_columns cols
 10           LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns cols_pk
 11              ON     cols.table_name = cols_pk.table_name
 12                 AND cols.column_name = cols_pk.column_name
 13           LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons
 14              ON     cols_pk.owner = cons.owner
 15                 AND cols_pk.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
 16           LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons_pk
 17              ON     cons.r_owner = cons_pk.owner
 18                 AND cons_pk.table_name = cols.table_name
 19     WHERE     cols.owner = 'SCOTT'
 20           AND cols.table_name = 'EMP'
 21  GROUP BY cols.table_name,
 22           cols.column_name,
 23           cols.data_type,
 24           cols.data_length,
 25           cons_pk.table_name,
 26           cols_pk.column_name,
 27           cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
 28  ORDER BY cols.column_name;
```

Result; there are 3 `DEPTNO` rows, i.e. *duplicates*:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMNNAME   COLUMNDATATYPE  COLUMNDATALENGTH P REFPROCNAME  COLUMNVALUEFIEL ISCHOOSABLE
---------- ------------ --------------- ---------------- - ------------ --------------- -----------
EMP        COMM         NUMBER                        22                                          0
EMP        DEPTNO       NUMBER                        22 R EMP          DEPTNO                    0
EMP        DEPTNO       NUMBER                        22 R EMP          DEPTNO                    0
EMP        DEPTNO       NUMBER                        22 R EMP          DEPTNO                    1
EMP        EMPNO        NUMBER                        22 P              EMPNO                     0
EMP        ENAME        VARCHAR2                      10                                          0
EMP        HIREDATE     DATE                           7                                          0
EMP        JOB          VARCHAR2                       9                                          0
EMP        MGR          NUMBER                        22                                          0
EMP        SAL          NUMBER                        22                                          0

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Your query, modified - see lines #11 and #20:

```
SQL>   SELECT cols.table_name,
  2           cols.column_name AS COLUMNNAME,
  3           cols.data_type AS COLUMNDATATYPE,
  4           cols.data_length AS COLUMNDATALENGTH,
  5           MAX (cons.constraint_type) AS PK,
  6           cons_pk.table_name AS REFPROCNAME,
  7           cols_pk.column_name AS COLUMNVALUEFIELD,
  8           CASE WHEN cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ISCHOOSABLE
  9      FROM all_tab_columns cols
 10           LEFT JOIN all_cons_columns cols_pk
 11              ON     cols.owner = cols_pk.owner                        -- this is optionally missing
 12                 AND cols.table_name = cols_pk.table_name
 13                 AND cols.column_name = cols_pk.column_name
 14           LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons
 15              ON     cols_pk.owner = cons.owner
 16                 AND cols_pk.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name
 17           LEFT JOIN all_constraints cons_pk
 18              ON     cons.r_owner = cons_pk.owner
 19                 AND cons_pk.table_name = cols.table_name
 20                 AND cons.constraint_name = cons_pk.constraint_name    -- this is surely missing
 21     WHERE     cols.owner = 'SCOTT'
 22           AND cols.table_name = 'EMP'
 23  GROUP BY cols.table_name,
 24           cols.column_name,
 25           cols.data_type,
 26           cols.data_length,
 27           cons_pk.table_name,
 28           cols_pk.column_name,
 29           cons_pk.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
 30  ORDER BY cols.column_name;
```

Result: no more `DEPTNO` duplicates:

```
TABLE_NAME COLUMNNAME   COLUMNDATATYPE  COLUMNDATALENGTH P REFPROCNAME  COLUMNVALUEFIEL ISCHOOSABLE
---------- ------------ --------------- ---------------- - ------------ --------------- -----------
EMP        COMM         NUMBER                        22                                          0
EMP        DEPTNO       NUMBER                        22 R EMP          DEPTNO                    1
EMP        EMPNO        NUMBER                        22 P              EMPNO                     0
EMP        ENAME        VARCHAR2                      10                                          0
EMP        HIREDATE     DATE                           7                                          0
EMP        JOB          VARCHAR2                       9                                          0
EMP        MGR          NUMBER                        22                                          0
EMP        SAL          NUMBER                        22                                          0

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm closer to the result I want thanks to you. but now I noticed that my PRINTERNAME column comes from a table named PRINTER. In the REFPROCNAME column, it should write PRINTER, not MACHINEPRINTER as in the image. Do you have a solution suggestion for this as well?
https://prnt.sc/KMR_CFjgyTon